# App crashes malloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, voip

I've been working on a Linphone custom, it all works fine except that every other call I receive when the app is running on the background ou when the phone is locked, I get this error. 
But its like every other call or so...
If anyone could help me =D

```
Joels-Mac linphone[2257]: linphone(2257,0x700000104000) malloc: *** error for object 0x61800001c6c0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Oct 17 17:36:20 Joels-Mac com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.3ED2130C-2343-49A3-93CA-24776C42E4D8.launchd_sim[1395] (UIKitApplication:com.routerbox.phoneboxcliente[0x73ea][2257]): Service exited due to Abort trap: 6
Oct 17 17:36:20 Joels-Mac SpringBoard[1412]: UNSUserNotificationServerConnectionListener connection invalidated
```

Comment: Using Linphone custom you are able to have VOIP call while in app and unable to have VOIP call while you are in background or app is killed or phone is locked, right ?

Comment: whenever the app is running on the background or the phone is locked, sometimes i get the calls and sometimes the app is killed.

Comment: Linphone custom is a SDK for VOIP ( WebRTC ). Does this SDK works in background or in kill state?

Comment: Works in background.